# Armory paper Backup

Tags: armory, paper-wallet, private-key-export

I have the paper backup for Armory Wallet but do not have access to the computer which the Wallet was created. 
How to I export the BTC?

Answer (score 3):

You can just import the backup on another computer with armory installed. It's not dependent on the computer it was created on.

Remember: The coins don't actually reside on your computer - The public ledger called "blockchain" holds the amount you own. You rather hold the private key in your wallet app, that allows you to sign transactions and thus send money.

Comment: Hi Michael,  Thanks for getting back to me!  I'm still stuck. I created a Blockchain wallet, thinking it would make it possible to spend, but I can't find the means to import the coin. (they make it look easy, but I'm not doing it right...???) I have an Armory Paper Backup Wallet version 1.35. Any hints here?? thanks!

Comment: I think it would be easiest, to import the Armory Backup back into another install of Armory and then send the funds to your Blockchain wallet. I know it's a bit of a hassle (since you need to download the blockchain again) but I don't think you can import the Armory backups into other apps. You explicitly need to export your private keys to do so. 

upside is, Bitcoin will get more user friendly in the future.

Comment: That makes sense.  I appreciate you taking the time with me.

Comment: you're very welcome. Could you pls mark my reply as a correct answer if it helped you, so others see the question was answered :) Thanks!